# iOS: Implement a rotating wheel with custom views being horizontally stationary

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I am fairly skilled iOS developer and wan't to implement a rotating wheel as illustrated below:

[image]

The wheel will consist of one big ring, i.e. the wheel itself, and a number of views spread out on it, in this case illustrated as circles with labels inside.

When the use drags on one of these views, the entire wheel should rotate, moving the views (circles) around, but keeping them horizontally stationary, as illustrated below:

[image]

I am both looking for examples of something similar already implemented or links to tutorials, that might help get closer to a solution. Any hints will be helpful.

### Edit: Solution

Combining [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17956609/746968) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235425/746968) I finally got a fully working spinning wheel with stationary views. Thank you.

Comment: yesterday someone asked a similar question. Take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936955/revolving-animation-that-follows-finger-of-uibuttons-that-follows-outer-path-o#comment26210564_17936955

Comment: @LucasEduardo Add that as an answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Take a look at the answer of this question. I think the two problems are very similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936955/revolving-animation-that-follows-finger-of-uibuttons-that-follows-outer-path-o#comment26210564_17936955

Comment: The here were very useful - but I don't see the implementation of keeping the labels horizontal as the wheel turns?